# Google Maps API 3 - JavaScript: Cycling-How to find elevation along the route?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any class for finding the elevation along a Cycling route the way google maps does it? As you can see in the link below, when you hover your mouse over the elevation, it also shows that point of the route on the map.

https://www.google.ie/maps/dir/Galway/Dublin/@53.0456335,-7.8289246,9z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x485b93955a2d5bff:0x32b1b440a495281!2m2!1d-9.0567905!2d53.270668!1m5!1m1!1s0x48670e80ea27ac2f:0xa00c7a9973171a0!2m2!1d-6.2603097!2d53.3498053!3e1 ,

The only class i can find in google is elevation along a path, which isnt very useful!

Finding the lat-lng coordinates of the route and then using the elevation API to find the elevation at those points does not reliably work. This is because the elevation provided by the elevation API does not factor in bridges and overpasses.

When searching the a route in Google maps, the elevation profile somehow knows the actual road elevation along the route, and hence it represents a bridge over a steep cliff quite accurately (rather than showing the steep drop). Travelling over a bridge such as the one linked below will yield a sharp dropoff by the elevation API since it knows that geographically there is a cliff, and it is unaware that the lat-lng provided has a bridge in that location.

Google Maps built-in elevation profile shows no cliff: 
https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/49.3040568,-123.1452437/49.3229241,-123.1317054/@49.3169602,-123.145165,14.75z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e1
Elevation API profile for the same route will show the cliff.

Is there a way to get accurate route elevation data? Not just the elevation of raw geographical features at particular lat-lng coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Google Maps "Elevation API" to obtain the elevation information. Just provide the location (lat&lng) or set of locations in the get request, and parse the result.

Take a look at the following URL and see how it is constructed for a JSON response:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=53.3237817,-8.7792418

Hope this helps.

EDIT: 
There could be some ready to use components available, but I didn't search for them.
Since this is a programming site and I believe you are programmer, you may want to code it yourself according to your spec.

There are some examples in the Google developers site.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation

A working example can be found in this link: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths

Here is a basic approach for this:

- Show a map to the user based on their location
- Let them select a starting point and a destination
- Show available path(s), if multiple path available then let them choose one
- Along the path, programmatically select x number of locations, get their geo coordinates
- Find their elevations (using Google Elevation API)
- Display the info in a list or as elevation profile graph (like in
  your example)
- Provide a click handler for it so that it will highlight the
  corresponding location on the map once you click.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply! The only thing I can get from that is elevation along a straight line, rather than elevation along roads/routes! Would you happen to know where i could find an example of some code that may do this?

Comment: Just edited my answer to give you more information. BTW, I don't know if there is any ready to use components out there (probably there is but I didn't do an exhaustive search for it), nevertheless, I explained a basic approach that you can take and implement it according to you requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Google has not made their elevation data (displayed in the elevation profile for cycling and walking) available via any of their APIs. They only allow access to the "natural landscape" elevation data through the [elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start).